# A good memorial song for a sister who passed away

Tags: discussion

I had a sister who passed away last year when she was thirteen. I want a good memorial song for her to play while showing her photos on a projector in my wedding.

Comment: First of all, sorry for your loss. However, I think the question is off-topic here, it is way to opinion based. Having said that, I would play a song that meant much to her.

Comment: Welcome to the site, sorry to hear about the circumstances. For a small (family) ceremony, I agree that the ideal song would be one that she liked, that means something to you too, would be familiar to those attending the ceremony, and would work as a celebration of her life and fit with the photos you're showing. Quite a tough choice! Sometimes instrumentals can work better than tracks with vocals, as they are less distracting. You might be able to find an instrumental version of a favourite song of hers, maybe?

Comment: @Magnilex thank you,im sorry i dont know what I must answer in english in this situations.
im searching to much for it,but i cant find something that satisfy me completely.i want to know others opinions.maybe they know something that i dont know

Comment: @topomorto thank you and thank you again,in culture we respond that with im sorry for your loses too.she was a very happy kid and the songs she liked was very high tempo and disco like.i will consider your opnion of course.thanks for helping me.

Comment: While this question is very much off topic on the main site, I have no problem with it on Meta. I'm sorry for your loss, and I hope you find a good song to remember her by.

Comment: However, condolences aside, I can't see how this question makes any sense on the meta site either. It is not about this site or its community at all. Meta seems rather inappropriate as a dump for questions that are just deemed too opinion-based for the main site, that's not what meta is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for your loss. My wife went through this process a few years after we married when her brother died suddenly. She was putting together a slideshow as well. She went with a quasi-religious song even though her brother had probably never heard it and probably wouldn't have liked it, it just seemed fitting.

Having said that, there is this song https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A7ry4cx6HfY which although from a metal band (that I don't really like), is actually quite emotionally rich, written for their drummer who had passed away. If the music style is a little too harsh, you can find acoustic covers online.

Good luck with your new life with your wife.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that your sister liked is what you should play. That's just what I think, but there's no right or wrong answer here. Honour her with her favourite music.